# Shelosha Ushloshim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred thirty-three?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Sifri - Kehas, Rivka & Ben Azai all lived for 133 years. If Rivka lived for 133 years then she would have been 14 years old when she married Yitzchok

http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=24029&st=&pgnum=34

Naftali the son of Yaakov Avinu lived for 133 years.

Comment: The Sifri I saw (http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34328&st=&pgnum=217) has Kehas and Rivkah as a pair who died at the same age.  Where is Ben Azai mentioned?

Comment: My comment is based on the following link from the Daas Zekeinim - http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=24029&st=&pgnum=34

Answer (score 8):

There were 133 Jewish victims of the 1929 Arab riots in Hebron:

Comment: Libi Astaire, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for the sad but appropriate contribution to the mi.yodeya series! We'd love to have you as a fully-registered member, which you can accomplish by clicking "register," above.

Answer (score 6):

According to the Midrash that Rivka was 14 when she married, she was 133 when she died ([Sifri 357](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34328&st=&pgnum=217))

14 years when she got married

20 years later she had Yaakov

63 years later Yaakov got the brachos and went toward Padam Aram

14 years in Yeshiva Shem v'Ever

20 years in Lavan's house

1 1/2 years in Sukkos

1/2 year in Shechem

Comment: I wouldn't have put a separate answer for the calculation.  I believe we were writing (almost) simultaneously.

Answer (score 5):

133 years in Kohot's life (Miriam,Aharon,and Moshe's father)

Comment: Kehot was their grandfather, not their father.

Comment: Source? Do you mean Amram's life?

Answer (score 5):

The 133th day from Rosh Hashanna is Tu Bishvat, if both Heshvan and Kislev are Haserim (have only 29 days)

Comment: I like it because it points out the uniqueness of those two months' lengths.

Answer (score 2):

133 years that Yisrael had been exiled prior to the exile of Yehudah.
Artscroll Eichah pg. 22 note 1